# INI file to multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, ini

I have the next INI file:

```
a.b.c = 1
a.b.d.e = 2
```

I am parsing this file using parse_ini_file. And it returns:

```
array(
    'a.b.c' => 1,
    'a.b.d.e' => 2
)
```

But I want to create a multidimensional array. My outout should be:

```
array(
    'a' => array(
        'b' => array(
            'c' => 1,
            'd' => array(
                'e' => 2
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I see it:

```
<?php

class ParseIniMulti {

    public static function parse($filename) {
        $ini_arr = parse_ini_file($filename);
        if ($ini_arr === FALSE) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        self::fix_ini_multi(&$ini_arr);
        return $ini_arr;
    }

    private static function fix_ini_multi(&$ini_arr) {
        foreach ($ini_arr AS $key => &$value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                self::fix_ini_multi($value);
            }
            if (strpos($key, '.') !== FALSE) {
                $key_arr = explode('.', $key);
                $last_key = array_pop($key_arr);
                $cur_elem = &$ini_arr;
                foreach ($key_arr AS $key_step) {
                    if (!isset($cur_elem[$key_step])) {
                        $cur_elem[$key_step] = array();
                    }
                    $cur_elem = &$cur_elem[$key_step];
                }
                $cur_elem[$last_key] = $value;
                unset($ini_arr[$key]);
            }
        }
    }

}


var_dump(ParseIniMulti::parse('test.ini'));
```

Answer (score 4):

It's actually quite simple, you only need to change the format of the array you already have by exploding it's key:

```
$ini_preparsed = array(
    'a.b.c' => 1,
    'a.b.d.e' => 2
);


$ini = array();
foreach($ini_preparsed as $key => $value)
{
    $p = &$ini;
    foreach(explode('.', $key) as $k)
        $p = &$p[$k];
    $p = $value;
}
unset($p);

print_r($ini);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [b] => Array
                (
                    [c] => 1
                    [d] => Array
                        (
                            [e] => 2
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

See as well: [String with array structure to Array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8537148/367456).

Comment: I think you need to organize it into recursion

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Zend_Config_Ini](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.adapters.ini.html) class. It does what you want, you can use it standalone (without the rest of Zend Framework) and as a bonus it supports section inheritance.

With the `toArray` method you can create an array from the config object.

Comment: Thank you. I have checked Zend_Config_Ini code fo using in my application)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [PHProp](https://github.com/amsa/PHProp).

Similar to `Zend_Config_Ini`, but you can refer to a key in your config like `${key}`

Answer (score 0):

It's a my class for parsing config ini files to a multidimensional array:

```
class Cubique_Config {
    const SEPARATOR = '.';

    private static $_data = null;

    public static function get() {
        if (is_null(self::$_data)) {
            $commonIniFile = APP . '/config' . '/common.ini';
            $envIniFile = APP . '/config' . '/' . ENV . '.ini';
            if (!file_exists($commonIniFile)) {
                throw new Exception('\'' . $commonIniFile . '\' config file not found');
            }
            if (!file_exists($envIniFile)) {
                throw new Exception('\'' . $envIniFile . '\' config file not found');
            }
            $commonIni = parse_ini_file($commonIniFile);
            $envIni = parse_ini_file($envIniFile);
            $mergedIni = array_merge($commonIni, $envIni);
            self::$_data = array();
            foreach ($mergedIni as $rowKey => $rowValue) {
                $explodedRow = explode(self::SEPARATOR, $rowKey);
                self::$_data = array_merge_recursive(self::$_data, self::_subArray($explodedRow, $rowValue));
            }
        }
        return self::$_data;
    }

    private static function _subArray($explodedRow, $value) {
        $result = null;
        $explodedRow = array_values($explodedRow);
        if (count($explodedRow)) {
            $firstItem = $explodedRow[0];
            unset($explodedRow[0]);
            $result[$firstItem] = self::_subArray($explodedRow, $value);
        } else {
            $result = $value;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```